# ASP.NET MVC web application deployment to heroku

Tags: c#, asp.net, heroku, model-view-controller

NET MVC web application with connection to database (Postgresql) and I have to deploy it to Heroku. Do I have to migrate this project to ASP.NET Core somehow or it is possible to deploy as it is?

My project structure :

[image]

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/PAT3YEDU/does-heroku-support-net-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deploy ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework) to Heroku. You need to migrate on .NET Core.

2 options of deployment .net core app to Heroku

- Docker https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker
- Using custom buildpack https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack